# Scroll Depth trigger works wrongly, is this a GA4 issue?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've set up a Trigger on GTM with thresholds - 25%, 50%, 75% and 90%.
On GA4 I have a report for seeing the scroll depths per path.

What I notice is that most of the pages have a higher hit on the 90% scroll depth as compared to the 25%.

Isn't this wrong? That a 90% can't be triggered without the 25% first being triggered?
What I have is a blog and these are not pages with endless scroll.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: on pages that fit the screen are all scroll events fired?

Comment: @TonyMcCreath - I don't have a page that fully fits as such. But I see where you're going with this. Let me identify short content pages and see how the behaviour is. Thanks!

Comment: also check what events are sent when you scroll to the bottom right away. But yes, generally, seeing 90% over 25% indicates a logical bug in GTM. If you find the bug in the events by inspecting them on pages, then it's gtm. Otherwise - GA4 report is misleading.

Comment: @BNazaruk - thanks for the pointer, will do!